# How to know the default spacing between chapters parts etc?

Tags: spacing, sectioning, formatting

I know there are some similar questions like this. But everyone asked about how to change the spacing and others suggested to use `titlesec` package. But I wanna know the default value of those spacing using a command. Can anyone help me?

Comment: It depends on the document class.  If you look at book.cls (for example) for `\chapter` (actually `\@makeshapterhead`) you will find a 50pt gap above, a 20pt gap between and a 40pt gap below.

Comment: can you tell me more about this? I don't only want to know about chapters, but also parts, sections, subsections, etc. Is there any similar commands like this? and what about the space below chapter? and did you mean `\@makechapterhead`? Ig you missed type it.

Comment: On my computer, book.cls is found in `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base`,  Yes, it was a typo.  Lastly, `\section` etc. are all implemented using `\@startsection` where the skip distances are the second and fourth arguments (absolute values).  See source2e.doc.

Comment: Oh thanks I have found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A chapter starts on a new page with 50pt space above it.

A section has 3.5ex space above it and the lower level divisions have 3.25ex space above them. Read the code for the standard classes (`> texdoc report`) will get you those.

Comment: do I need to type `>` or you mean terminal by this? And is it necessary to use `report` or I need to use `<documentclass>` instead of report? And I am using overleaf. So if this is terminal then can you tell me how can I use this?

Comment: @rajin100000 The `>` is just an indication of the start of the terminal line. Go to a terminal and type `texdoc report`. That will produce the code for `article.cls`, `report.cls`, and `book.cls`. I have no idea about how `overleaf` does anything.

Comment: Yes it worked, however I can check texdoc.org in web.

Comment: @rajin100000 So you can, but it appears not to be as efficient as it seems you have to choose among multiple documents. But do whatever you think best.